# Eclipse doesn't recognize a jar I created with One-JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

So I wrote one class with main method that depends on another jar file which dependes on many jar files. To make things simpler, I used One-JAR and created a single executable jar.
The jar I created is fine, I was able to run it:

```
java -jar foo.jar
```

This executes my main application successfully.

Next, I created a new project in Eclipse and added the foo.jar to the build path via the "add external jars" (I do it all the time and it always works). For some reason, in my Eclipse project it complains that it doesn't recognize the package import from foo.jar.

I looked on previous questions on jar problems with Eclipse but none helped. I suspect it's something to do with the tree that One-Jar creates, but since "java -jar foo.jar" from the command line works fine, I don't understand why Eclipse doesn't see the class files.

Thanks!

Update:
Here's how my foo.jar created by One-Jar looks like:

```
META-INF     OneJar.class com          doc          lib          main
```

inside main:

```
main     main.jar
```

insides this main the package tree of my application with the .class files. Now, if I include "main.jar" in Eclipse, it does recognize my application. But then it doesn't recognize the other dependencies under lib/ so it throws run time exceptions.

Update 2:
So the problem with One-jar and Eclipse is not solved, but someone mentioned the fat jar Eclipse plugin so I tried it and it did the job perfectly. The jar it generated worked with both Eclipse and Maven. They actually support One-Jar as well, you can check the One-Jar option when creating the jar. I didn't use it but it's there (if it works it actually worth using because it should take care of library conflicts). 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The jar that one-jar creates is just a jar with classes in it.

Comment: Right. But let's say my package is com.example.main then it put the .class file under: main/main/com/example/main/

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're saying. I think it's doing that to avoid conflicts, similar to how shading works--not sure if one-jar has a non-mangling option or not.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will not understand jars inside jars. It is better to have the other jars included to build path separately.

Comment: Tried to include foo.jar and main.jar which compiled but didn't work in run-time because of the other jars dependency. I can add all the other jars separately, that would work, but I'm trying to avoid it. This is why I'm using One-Jar, which works from the command like but not via Eclipse.

Comment: ok, is there any specific reasons why you want to avoid it. because it is the usual way of adding dependent jars to the build path. in case if you want to bundle everything into one jar then you could unzip all the class files and bundle them in one single jar. it may sound stupid :). but i could not think of other ways...

Comment: It's more convenient to work with a single jar, and also much easier to ship it to someone else. And, One-Jar should resolve dependency conflicts (e.g., my app uses a commons library 3.4 and one of the libraries I depend on uses commons 2.4). One-Jar should be able to shade this.

Comment: just checked out about FatJar in eclipse. hope that is similar to what you are looking for  http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks @tsatiz, FatJar did the job.